# ASUS USB-N13 wireless adapter problems with Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: networking, adapter

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 and I am new to Linux and networking.  I am having trouble with my ASUS N-13 network adapter, I get a signal but that signal drops often. What can I do?

Comment: Have you googled for, e.g. "Ubuntu Trusty USB-n13" and/or "Ubuntu USB-n13"?  Chances are other people have had the same problem and already solved or reported it.

Answer (score 7):

If you're still looking for an answer to this, and for future users, there's a [great solution](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2205444&p=12967859#post12967859) which refers to the [original solution](https://github.com/pvaret/rtl8192cu-fixes).

I have just copied and pasted as is from the README:

> ### Installation
>
> Ensure you have the necessary prerequisites:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get install git linux-headers-generic build-essential dkms
> ```
>
> Clone this repository:
>
> ```
> git clone https://github.com/pvaret/rtl8192cu-fixes.git
> ```
>
> Set it up as a DKMS module:
>
> ```
> sudo dkms add ./rtl8192cu-fixes
> ```
>
> Build and install it:
>
> ```
> sudo dkms install 8192cu/1.11
> ```
>
> Refresh the module list:
>
> ```
> sudo depmod -a
> ```
>
> Ensure the native (and broken) kernel driver is blacklisted:
>
> ```
> sudo cp ./rtl8192cu-fixes/blacklist-native-rtl8192.conf /etc/modprobe.d/
> ```
>
> And reboot. You're done.

Comment: This worked flawlessly on 16.04!

Comment: If `sudo dkms install 8192cu/1.10` won't work, check directory **/usr/src/** for proper name (it was **/usr/src/8192cu-1.11/** for me so I had to use command `sudo dkms install 8192cu/1.11`)

Answer (score 0):

usb-n13 is very finnicky on dual boot system. when i am using full time linux, rebooting directly to linux from linux session, the card will give me full 40Mbs internet speed. Similarly, if i reboot directly to windows from windows session, it will give me full 40Mbps. And if I were to boot from linux to windows session, it will be full speed too. But, if i were to reboot to linux from windows session, the speed will degrade to 1 Mbps. To fix it, i unplugged and replugged, it will be behave good again at 40Mbps. All said, this is a very good card when it works.

Comment: Try to disable fast boot in bios, and report it in answer if helps