# wireless adapter asus-n13 keeps disconnecting

Tags: networking, drivers, usb, asus

I have just recently installed Ubuntu and I am new to Linux.

My network adaptor, Asus usb-n13, keeps disconnecting every few minutes and I lose internet connection.  the only way to connect back to the internet is to unplug and plug in the adaptor, which is aggravating because I have to do it so often.

I have tried the solution on [this forum post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/456759/asus-usb-n13-wireless-adapter-problems-with-ubuntu-14-04) but it didn't work.  When I typed in `sudo dkms add ./rtl8192cu-fixes` to the terminal, it says

> /usr/src/.-rtl8192cu-fixes does not exist

Does anyone know how to get the adapter to work, or even why it keeps disconnecting?

Answer (score 1):

Does previous command `git clone https://github.com/pvaret/rtl8192cu-fixes.git` works ? If it does not, you are trying this in /usr/src and maybe your user does not have rights in /usr/src. You can try run command with sudo like `sudo git clone https://github.com/pvaret/rtl8192cu-fixes.git` or first make git directory in your home directory and then run git command like `mkdir ~/git && cd ~/git && git clone https://github.com/pvaret/rtl8192cu-fixes.git`

Comment: I was able to install the dkms, but now when I type sudo depmod -a, it doesn't do anything.

Comment: nvm, downloading the dkms fixed it.  Ty